# Changing a power supply from DC output to AC output

Tags: power-supply, transformer

I've read an article on changing a 12 V AC-DC power supply to 9 V AC-AC by just tapping the transformer output directly, bypassing diodes and capacitor.

This only applies to older type AC power adaptors that have a large, heavy transformer. Does this modification change any aspects of the amperage? I'm trying to modify a 12 V, 1.6 A DC output power supply for a device requiring 9 V 2.1 A AC.

I also want to find out if amperage ratings for devices have any safety factor figured in, allowing for any lower amperage tolerance.

Comment: The VA rating of the transformer is likely to be a bit more than the watt rating of the DC output to cover losses. Other than that, there is not likely to be any safety factor built in. The transformer rating is likely to be a bit higher than 9 volts for a 12 volt regulated output.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't increase the current rating for the secondary unless you rewind the entire secondary. The manufacturer has placed a maximum current rating on the secondary for a (presumably) good reason, probably rated to the thickness of the wire. Removing some of the turns to lower the secondary voltage does not change the current carrying capability of that wire.

Comment: Thank you for the info